# How to disable modules during installation with Magento CLI?

Tags: magento2, installation

Is there a way to disable some modules during install using cli, same way as it is possible in web wizard? Or is there a way to force composer to not even download some modules?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the "replace" section in composer.json if you do not want to load any of the modules.

eg:
If you do not want to load yotpo/magento2-module-yotpo-reviews you can add the following in composer.json. This will remove yotpo module loading in /vendor folder.

```
"replace": {
  "yotpo/magento2-module-yotpo-reviews": "*"
}
```

Please let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way if you are using Magento 2.3 or above, you can use `--disable-modules`

#### Example

As you can see in the last line, you can specify many modules at the same time.

```
php -f bin/magento setup:install \
 --base-url='https://local.magento2.com/' \
 --db-host=db \
 --db-name=magento \
 --db-user=magento \
 --db-password=magento \
 --admin-firstname=Rafael \
 --admin-lastname=Correa \
 --admin-email=rgomes@lesite.ca \
 --admin-user=admin \
 --admin-password=adminpassword \
 --language=en_CA \
 --currency=CAD \
 --use-rewrites=1 \
 --backend-frontname=admin \
 --elasticsearch-host=elasticsearch \
 --disable-modules='Yotpo_Yotpo,Vertex_AddressValidation,Smile_ElasticsuiteVirtualCategory'
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to documentation? From which version is it possible?

Comment: This works starting with version 2.3

Comment: Could you provide a link to documentation?

Comment: Hi @michalhosna, I didn't find it in the DevDocs or any other documentation.

Answer (score -2):

You can disable existing modules using Magento CLI:

```
bin/magento module:disable Vendor_Module
```

If you want to download only specific modules using composer you have to create custom `composer.json` for this purpose, specifying only modules and libraries you'd like to fetch under `require` key.

Comment: Yes, i know that. I have an installation script for magento, and the current version is doing it exactly like that. But i wanted more like be able to disable modules before or during installation, like in web gui installation. But anyway, thanks!